# Separate 1,2,3 into individual 1 and 2 and 3

Tags: php, session, if-statement, session-variables

Can anybody help me, I have a session like this:

```
$_SESSION['SES_SA'] = 1,2,3
```

Then I want to use it like this:

```
if($_SESSION['SES_SA']=="1"){
  ......
}
elseif($_SESSION['SES_SA']=="2"){
  ......
}
elseif($_SESSION['SES_SA']=="3"){
  ......
}
```

Is it posible?

Comment: explode on comma? its not clear what you are asking

Comment: @rtfm yes, i mean i want to separate it  then call it only a number, example i want to call only number 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but not exactly the way way you presented. It can be done as following:

```
$_SESSION['SES_SA'] = explode(',',$_SESSION['SES_SA'])
if(in_array(1,$_SESSION['SES_SA']){
    ....
}
else if(in_array(2,$_SESSION['SES_SA']){
    ....
}
else if(in_array(3,$_SESSION['SES_SA']){
    ....
}
```

Comment: Monjur UI Hasan it said in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\appeg\esurat.php on line 3.

Comment: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\appeg\4dm1nw3b12545\show.php on line 6 when i used in different way